# What is the IAM policy required to call CreateEventSource from a Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda that can create a trigger on a dynamoDB table and setup the trigger to call another lambda.

I use node.js and was able to successfully test it all from command line.

But, when I deploy my lamdba and invoke the function using the Test option in AWS, I get an error. Which is basically an access issue.

My IAM policy is set to allow the lambda to access following in serverless.yml
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account:function:*

Is there any other permission I should give my Lambda to create the policy?

Here is my Lambda Code (node 8.10):

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: "us-" });

    exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    let streamARN = "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:<ACCOUNTID>:table/dev-<TABLE>/stream/2018-04-04<TIMESTAMP>";
    let functionName = "record-dynamo-table-history";

    var params = {
        "EventSourceArn": streamARN,
        "FunctionName": functionName,
        "StartingPosition": "LATEST",
        "BatchSize": 100
    };
    console.log("Check Status and Create Trigger:" + JSON.stringify(params, null, 2));
    try {
            console.log("Calling CreateEvent Source.");
            const eventResults = await lambda.createEventSourceMapping(params).promise();
            console.log("Event Source Mapping Response:" + JSON.stringify(eventResults, null, 2));
            if (eventResults) {
                //check if streaming was enabled
                if (eventResults.hasOwnProperty("State")) {
                    console.log("State of create event is available")
                }
            }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error createEventSourceMapping" + err);
    }

    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
    }
```

Thanks,
Nachi

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: Sure, Here is the error `Error createEventSourceMappingAccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::<accountID>:assumed-role/ods-service-dev-us-west-2-lambdaRole/dev-xxxxxxx-create-dyno-table-trigger is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping on resource: *
END RequestId: _______someGUID____`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue at the end?

Comment: @all can anyone answer this question I am facing the same problem.

Comment: errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::522394378604:assumed-role/chequebooks-qr-dev-eu-central-1-lambdaRole/chequebooks-qr-dev-QrCodeGenerator is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping on resource: *